# Best Way to Move Things Around in CSS?

Tags: html, css

When I want to move anything (text, images, etc.) in CSS, I find myself using margin-top with ridiculous values like 1000 or even higher. Sometimes I set the position to fixed and I can move the object vertically, but not horizontally.

I guess what I'm trying to say is what is the best way to move things around in CSS? Set the position to fixed? Use "top" instead of "margin-top?" When to use padding. When to use display. etc.

I'm asking this because 1. I'm new to website design and 2. the practice site that I'm making keeps getting messed up (ex. things go behind other things, the site only works in full scree (half screen totally breaks it))

Comment: check http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: you can use float margin padding text-align and yes it all depends but keep practice and read professional article about designing you all get over it soon

Answer (score 2):

You're question is way too broad. There are so many factors that come into play, it would be impossible to answer. It's kind of like coming onto a car forum and asking "How do I rebuild this car? Every time I unbolt a part of the car, it breaks." There is a lot you have to learn before you can dive in and start creating a site, just like there is a lot you have to learn about cars before you can start rebuilding them. You have to understand how CSS and HTML layout works.

I recommend you start with a basic course, a great one that's recommended often is CodeAcademy, you can try it here: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web

By the way, you do not want to use position and/or margin to layout your page. That would be a nightmare to maintain. You have to use a combination of many different elements and properties to properly layout a page. In the beginning it will be very confusing, but if you stick with it, you will learn it.

Answer (score 0):

ok........

1st you need to learn html flow. You can position a lot of elements naturally using div and spans. Css should be used to modify width/ height etc for the majority of elements in this way. You should stick to natural flow as much as possible. Fixed position elements will remain fixed even when scrolling (unless inside div & some css...) so thats not really a solution for every element on your page.

Make a little effort to learn yourself and you will have it, unless you have a specific example of something you cant do, you should focus on tutorials of which there are plenty of.

Concentrate on html 1st and then start css tutorials such as width, dimensions of single elements, then classes of elements (elements with the same style).

Btw just to repeat myself..........position: relative; to keep in the flow, this trys to fit elements in a top to bottom and a little bit horizontal when you ask for it (span/ float: left/right;) enjoy!